# What (browser plugin?) defines p as a string www311

Tags: javascript

I have code which declares function p() and it fails seemingly randomly on some users. Debugging show that p has already been declared as a string "www311.". Anything in our code does not include such string so it must come from the browser.

I'm suspecting a browser plug-in but am unable to figure out what. The following user agents have gathered the aforementioned error:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0

Comment: *"Debugging show that p has already been declared as a string "www311.""* That wouldn't matter. As long as your declaration is processed *after* the earlier definition, you'll win. So it would have to be something happening *after* your declaration is processed, which seems surprising.

Comment: [`<a id="p" href="www311.">`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)?

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that the real problem is that you have these globals in your code :)

Use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to encapsulate your code.

Turn this:

```
 //your code
 function p(){
 }
 // this is in the global namespace.
```

Into this:

```
 (function(){ // functions get their own scope
     //your code
     function p(){ // p is no longer global
     }
 })(); // note that the function is immediately invoked here so you get the same result.
```

Alternatively, you can use a module loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) which will take care of the globals problem. Since you put modules in functions there too - you won't have to worry about globals.

Here is [an interesting read about it from Addy Osmani's "Learning JavaScript design patterns"](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)